# How to convert strings to DateTime C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have 3 separate strings with the following format:

`01-29-2016`: a date, picked from a bootstrap datepicker

`1:00am` start time, picked from a dropdown, format could also be e.g. 10:00pm

`2:30am` end time, picked from a dropdown, format could also be e.g. 11:30pm

Using the above strings I need to construct 2 DateTime properties that represent the time range, something like below:

`2016-01-29 02:30:00`

`2016-01-29 01:00:00`

I need the DateTime properties so I could update datetime database fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine both your time parts with date part respectively and use [`ParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) with `MM-dd-yyyyH:mmtt` format like;

```
var date = "01-29-2016";
var ts1 = "1:00am";
var ts2 = "2:30am";

var dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date + ts1, "MM-dd-yyyyH:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 29.01.2016 01:00:00
var dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date + ts2, "MM-dd-yyyyH:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// 29.01.2016 02:30:00
```